# Update records with ArcPy update cursor? Geodatabase format

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I try to update thousands of rows when all records get the same value.
My code has a loop that runs thousands of times.
Is it possible for the program to make the change to all the columns in one command and save run time ?

For example, php+mySQL can do this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE all_records SET Xcenter = $val1, Ycenter = $val2 WHERE ID > 100");
```

This is my code:

```
    for row in rows:
    row.setValue("Xcenter", val1)
    row.setValue("Ycenter", val2)
    rows.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the data storage format of the target (file geodatabase, RDBMS, shapefile,...) and provide a sample of your existing code.

Comment: Please add more code, since that fragment is missing cursor creation. Note that there are no versions of ArcGIS which aren't retired for which non-DataAccess cursors are appropriate. setRow is not supported on DataAcess cursor rows, and DataAcess cursors are much faster than the old, deprecated cursors. You also have indent issues.

Comment: exactly. I mean thousands of records. I updated. Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with a for loop? In essence, it's exactly what's going one behind the scenes of any other method, except, with a da cursor, it should be more efficient than using an unnecessary intermediary like CalculateField.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a weird feeling that you are looking for `arcpy.CalculateField_management` It is simple and quick [calculate field help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field.htm)

Comment: Great idea.. TNX :)

Answer (score 3):

Try the da.UpdateCursor:

```
import arcpy
feature_class = r'C:\data.gdb\features1'

val1 = 123
val2 = 456

sql = """{0} > 100""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(feature_class, 'ID'))

fields_to_update = ['Xcenter','Ycenter']
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature_class, fields_to_update, sql) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row = val1, val2
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: First of all thank you
Also in your program there is a loop that runs thousands of times (as many records)
I'm looking for something to do it at once.
The values I put are identical to all records so I do not want to run thousands of times in a loop

Comment: @Oz1988: The data  access cursors (da.UpdateCursor etc.) are very fast so thousands of rows should not be a problem, it should finish in a few seconds. This is what they are designed to do. I know no other way.

Comment: @Oz1988 If you had a large number of rows (tens to hundreds of millions), it would actually be **much** faster to set multiple values per row than to use the Field Calculator one column at a time. Your stated goal and intended methodology are incongruous.